# How do I rerender this img element?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm sending the API a remote image url. The API does some image processing, then uploads to AWS S3. If successful, it returns the url to the image in `response.data.attributes['image-url']`

My controller has:

```
imageUrl: Ember.computed.oneWay('model.imageUrl');

actions: {
  uploadImage(imageUrl) {
    Ember.$.ajax({
      url: `api/v1/users/1/update-image`,
      type: 'PUT',
      data: {
        data: {
          attributes: {
            'image-url': imageUrl
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .success(response => {
      this.set('imageUrl', response.data.attributes['image-url']);
    })
    .error(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

My template has:

```
<img src={{imageUrl}}>
```

API always returns something like `https://project1.imgix.net/products/1/image.jpg`. Even if `image.jpg` is an entirely new image.

Ember does not rerender the `img` element. I have to manually refresh to see the new image on the browser.

Is there any way I can tell Ember that the `img` element contains a new image and that it should re-render it?

Is there a different approach I should consider instead?

**EDIT**

So I tried setting `imageUrl` to `null` first, then wait a few seconds to set the actual image url. Seems to work, but is this the right way to tackle this situation:

```
.success(response => {
  this.set('imageUrl', null);

  Ember.run.later((() => {
    this.set('imageUrl', response.data.attributes['image-url'] + '?t=' + (new Date()).getTime());
  }), 3000);
})
```

I wonder if this has anything to do with running `this.set` at some specific Ember run loop.

Comment: When looking at the controller in the ember chrome extension, is the `imageURL` being set properly? Have you tried setting `model.imageURL` instead of `imageURL` directly? I haven't worked with `oneWay` yet, so I'm not sure if you can set the value through that.

Comment: .success(response => {
          this.set('imageUrl', response.data.attributes['image-url'] + '?t=' + (new Date()).getTime());
    })

Comment: @pbogut That seems to work with the combination of `Ember.run.later`. See my edit

Comment: Try notifying the property changed after value is set. this.notifyPropertyChange('imageURL');

Answer (score 1):

To manually let ember know a property has changed, use the **[notifyPropertyChange](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange)**. This should make ember recompute and bindings or computed propwerties based on your property. You can use it as `this.notifyPropertyChange('imageURL');`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `oneWay` will prevent you from setting that value.

> Where computed.alias aliases get and set, and allows for bidirectional data flow, computed.oneWay only provides an aliased get. The set will not mutate the upstream property, rather causes the current property to become the value set. This causes the downstream property to permanently diverge from the upstream property.

[Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_oneWay)

Try changing:

```
this.set('imageUrl', response.data.attributes['image-url']);
```

to

```
this.set('model.imageUrl', response.data.attributes['image-url']);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. However, I do notice that doing `this.set('imageUrl', 'https://project1.imgix.net/products/1/foo.jpg');` will re-render the `img` element. Keep in mind though that `foo.jpg` does not exist. Was just trying to see if the actual re-render works with a new filename. Which it does

Comment: So if you pass it the URL of an existing image (google search an image and use that URL) then it works, just not with `response.data.attributes['image-url']`? Maybe check what that attribute is actually returning?

Comment: It only works if the value of `imageUrl` has changed completely

Comment: Ahh. I'm sorry, I didn't understand that part. I didn't realize the URL wasn't a unique URL for each image. I imagine your solution of attaching the time stamp to it would help. Seems like you could set that directly and it'd be enough for glimmer to realize it has changed and therefore change the image. No need for null or delayed setting.